# Checkstyle validation fail when needs multiple lines

Tags: regex, eclipse, checkstyle

I need to perform a validation rule on eclipse checkstyle, after a key **{** of method and before end key **}** should have a empty line, example:

```
public void wrongMethod() {
    System.out.println("wrong method");
}
```

correct

```
public void correctMethod() {

    System.out.println("correct method");

}
```

I try to use a **RegexpMultiline** in checkstyle rules xml file, doing some like this:

```
<module name="RegexpMultiline">
    <property name="format" value=".+\{\n.+[;]"/>
    <property name="message" value="should have empty line"/>
</module>
```

sure, this Regex expression can be better, the issue is, the multiline behavior works in a [regex simulator site](http://regexpal.com/) with the examples above, but in checkstyle dont. I search on a checkstyle documentation and not found a ready reature for this.

Anyone know a solution for this issue?

thanks.

Comment: And did you try `<property name="format" value=".+\{\n+.+;"/>`?

Comment: Hello, i try now, but don´t works, i take in mind if **\n** don´t works in any case in checkstyle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you run the check on files with `CRLF` line endings. If yes, then remember about `\r` in your pattern.

This works for me:

```
<module name="RegexpMultiline">
    <property name="format" value="\{[\r]?\n(?![\r]?\n)"/>
    <property name="message" value="should have empty line"/>
</module>
```

I've changed couple of things in the pattern:

- `.+` at the beginning is not needed
- no need to match `;`
- [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is used

Comment: Thanks, it works, i made a little modification, because the rule validade other things beyond methods: **(public|private|protected).+\{[\r]?\n(?![\r]?\n)**. Now i will try to do the rule for the end of the method on the close key.